# Upgrade script cannot find newer release

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

One of my servers is unable to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) to newer versions:

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=quantal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.10"

$ cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades | grep -v '^$\|^\s*\#'
[DEFAULT]
Prompt=normal
```

(also tried with Prompt=lts)

```
$sudo apt-get update
...

$sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new ubuntu release
No new release found
```

Tried to change servers to `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com` (got from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)), and from digitalOcean but result is the same.

Eventually I upgraded this server using the following steps:

1. Backup `/etc/apt/sources.list` file
2. Changed original servers to [old-releases.ubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)
3. Changed all `quantal` to `raring` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file
4. Updated package lists (apt-get update)
5. Updated packages (apt-get dist-upgrade) - everything completed smoothly
6. Rebooted server
7. Checked for new distribution (sudo do-release-upgrade -d) - still not found
8. Changed `raring` to `saucy`  in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file
9. Repeated steps 4-7 with same results
10. Restored backed-up `/etc/apt/sources.list` file
11. Changed `saucy` to `trusty`  in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file
12. Repeated steps 4-7 with same results

Now I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) release. It is OK until 2019-04, but it still cannot find upgrades.

**Is there a way to restore the ability of an Ubuntu distribution to upgrade using the `do-release-upgrade` script?**

Command line solution is highly preferred.

Comment: You can not upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04 a supported way. It is better to install 14.04. You can keep all data.

Comment: @muru: I had used a solution with old-releases from this page. It had not helped.

Comment: Post the actual output of `sudo apt-get update` when you used the `old-releases` mirror.

Comment: @muru: apt-get update gives no errors. Output is [here](http://pastebin.com/MUm696BX)

Comment: Changing the code name in sources.list is the Debian way to do upgrades. As long as you have a backup to go to if you fail in your task, this would be your only option to upgrade. You might need to do a combination of `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `aptitude dist-upgrade` to get your server up to date. Aptitude deletes programs so make sure you have a backup of the installed files `dpkg --get-selections > /safe/location`

Comment: Upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) by changing release name in sources.list and still have the same issue - "No new release found". It is definitely some kind of configuration problem, but I cannot understand where to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to 14.04, download it's .iso file, burn it onto a flash drive. You will get an option to upgrade during the installation process, similar to the one in the image. You won't loose your data stored in your /home directory.

Now if you are on a server and cannot do it like this,you can do it from the command line, but it will require some effort. You can only upgrade to the next distro. So you need to upgrade to the next version, which is 13.04, and so on ultil you get to your LTS. Canonical may have removed the sources for 13.04, but digitalOcean still provides the sources for old releases [here](http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu-old/).

So update your sources.list with that from digitalocean and then upgrade
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo do-release-update

[image]

Comment: 1. No CD at server. 2. I have only ssh console access. Updated question.

Comment: @YuriyPetrovskiy, I've updated my answer. I see that your sources seem to be working fine.  But you could try the alternative source.

Comment: Done that also. No changes. Even after manually changing `quantal` to `raring` and updating `update-manager-core` to newer one.

Comment: @YuriyPetrovskiy did you try without a `-d` option?

Comment: Yes. Same result.